# Need to write an android application with an AR function

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I need to write an android application with an AR function like [iTagged](http://www.itagged.com/) but simpler.
User hold the mobile, then turning the camera toward a house, then add some note.
Other peoples can see these notes on the same house.

What framework can i use?

Comment: Vuforia (https://www.qualcomm.com/products/vuforia)

Comment: I am using [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/pricing) for my AR app. Used to be totally free with no limits or watermarks. Now they have different plans (starter etc.) with the starter plan remain free with some limits.

Comment: Vuforia includes: Image Targets, Multi - Targets, Cylinder Targets, Frame Markers, Text Recognition, Object Targets, Smart Terrain. So, which function is use for my purpose? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DroidAR. It is a framework for Augmented Reality on Android. 
It supports Location based AR & marker based AR.
& its under GPL License.

https://github.com/bitstars/droidar

Comment: Thanks you very much. May be iTagged use location based AR as you say.  I don't think they can recognize all object over the world, just storage lat/lon information, then use it for another users

Comment: You are welcome :)
as i saw iTagged this is what i sensed they are doing. from my small experience in AR, this is the way i would do it. (using a location based recognition).
Do not forget to share your app once you are done ;)